# Restoring a database dump throws lots of «could not open file "base/nnnnn/nnnnn"» errors

Tags: database, postgresql, psql, pg-dump, postgresql-14

I'm trying to restore a database dump from Render locally which worked fine in the past. But now I get lots of errors.

```
$ PGPASSWORD="###" pg_dump -h ###.render.com -O -U app_production app_production >dump.sql
$ psql -U app_production -f dump.sql app_production
```

The errors usually start when the indexes are recreated:

```
(...)
CREATE INDEX
CREATE INDEX
CREATE INDEX
CREATE INDEX
CREATE INDEX
CREATE INDEX
ERROR:  could not open file "base/16388/18035": No such file or directory
CONTEXT:  writing block 0 of relation base/16388/18035
parallel worker
ERROR:  could not open file "base/16388/18035": No such file or directory
CONTEXT:  writing block 1 of relation base/16388/18035
ERROR:  could not open file "base/16388/18035": No such file or directory
CONTEXT:  writing block 2 of relation base/16388/18035
ERROR:  could not open file "base/16388/18035": No such file or directory
CONTEXT:  writing block 3 of relation base/16388/18035
(...)
```

I have reinstalled everything on my local (macOS Ventura) machine, all of Homebrew, PostgreSQL etc. Tried different dumps as well, which results sometimes in a few, sometimes in lots of such errors.

Any idea what's going on here?

Thanks a lot for your hints!

Comment: Please share more details. How is this problem related to programming?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out: Apparently, in a comments table, someone posted a text which contains the base64 encoded signature of a macOS malware. ClamAV recognizes this and quarantines the database file during import (for some reason, notifications were off). When the import rebuilds the indexes, this database inconsistency causes the errors.